# How to get the computers domain name in matlab?

Tags: matlab, domain-name

I tried getting domain name in c# as below,

```
IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
Console.WriteLine("Domain name:   {0}", properties.DomainName);
```

I have searched similar kind of approach in matlab for finding domain name. But I am not successful. Could anyone help me out like how we can get the domain name matlab(The domain name looks like yyy.xxxxx.com).

I got to know how to get computer name as below:

```
cc=getenv('computername');
```

Comment: Do you mean `name = getenv('HOSTNAME');?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
[s,cout] = system('net config workstation | findstr /C:"Full Computer name"');
FQDN= strtrim(strrep(cout,'Full Computer name',''))
FQDN=
XXXX.YYYY.com
```

This returns the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the computer .  Where XXXX is your PC Name and YYYY is the domain.

Similarly if you just want the domain name:

```
[s,cout] = system('systeminfo | findstr /C:"Domain:"');
Domain = strtrim(strrep(cout,'Domain:',''))
Domain =
YYYY.com
```

EDIT: You can also get the FQDN using java in matlab like this:

```
FQDN = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getCanonicalHostName 
FQDN = 
XXXX.YYYY.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read from the environment variable:

```
getenv('USERDOMAIN')
```

Comment: I want the domain that we see when we do right click on the machine name and then properties. There we see the computer name, domain name. The domain name looks like corp.xxxxx.com. I want to get this domain name.

Comment: Open the command line executor and execute command `set`. You will see a bunch of environment variables like: `USERDNSDOMAIN`, `USERDOMAIN`. Does anyone of them contain the information you want?

Comment: @Romeo: In an AD forest with trust relationships between domains, the user's domain might not be the same as the computer's domain.